# How to use Angular library from npm package?

Tags: angular

I have created a lib Angular by command:

```
ng generate library wrapper-cesium-panorama
```

Then I build it:

```
ng build cesium-panorama-lib
```

After I moved to `/dict/cesium-panorama-lib` folder and made:

```
npm publish
```

It cratead a npm package.

Then I have installed this package in existing Angular app:

```
npm i cesium-panorama-lib
```

It created package in `/node_modules` folder:

[image]

I try to use this library in Angular app:

```
import { CesiumPanoramaLibModule } from "cesium-panorama-libi";
```

It can not find path. Then I tried:

```
import { CesiumPanoramaLibModule } from "cesium-panorama-lib/src/public-api";
imports: [CesiumPanoramaLibModule]
```

It works, but after build app I got this message:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/cesium-panorama-lib/src/public-api.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: C:\Users\poDesktop\AngularPrototype\node_modules\cesium-panorama-lib\src\public-api.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the Angular Package Format
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (C:\Users\ponom\Desktop\AngularPrototype\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:913:23)
```

What do I do wrong and how to use it? I meantored that other packages has `index.js` in root directory

Comment: isn't it just a typo? you said at your first try you typed: `import { CesiumPanoramaLibModule } from "cesium-panorama-libi";` you typed **libi**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should export all your component and modules you want expose in `public-api.ts`

then when you have installed your library you should be able to import your modules/component like this: `import { CesiumPanoramaLibModule } from "cesium-panorama-lib";`

if you cannot import it like this, then you have a problem in your library

Comment: I got you, I will verify all and post the answer here